# Separate clipboard for torbrowser

Tags: clipboard, tor

I'm running torbrowser on Debian. klipper saves the history of my clipboard. I would like to desactivate this feature for tor browser, so that I can use the copy-paste functions "locally", without sharing them with the rest of my system.

Is that achievable? Is this a linux-oriented question?

Comment: no idea if it is achievable but it is definitely a Linux oriented and not Tor oriented. Also, you have to realize that it can be a different answer depending which desktop you are using: KDE, Gnome, XFCE, etc. so make sure that you mention that also.

Comment: The OP reasked their question on U&L, after which their tor post (this one) was migrated to U&L. Closing as a duplicate of the (higher-voted) original at U&L.